# Keras LSTM Network Input Format

Tags: python, keras

I have a time series of regressors `v_{1}, v_{2}, ... v_{T}` where each `v_{i}` is a vector of dimension `(1 x 9). Say v_{1} = [1, 1.1, 2.3, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0.2, -0.3]`. I have another time series `y_{1}, y_{2}, ... y_{T}` each of which is a scalar. The goal is to predict

`y_{t+L} = f(v_{t}, v_{t-1}, v_{t-2}, ..., v_{t-M})` for some function f. I want to forecast L steps ahead with regressors looking back upto M.

How do I create an LSTM network? I am confused by the documentation.

I started with

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(" What goes here?"))
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want only a network definition or data shift also?

Comment: I am interested in how the data shift works. I have seen the documentation on the network definition but don't understand it well either. Just a few layered LSTM with one input layer, say two hidden layers and one output layer to do this regression will suffice.

Comment: Does this help at all? http://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful. I am making progress on it.